# How to change current code to read from 2 different OneWire devices?

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I've been given this code which reads from a OneWire temperature device DS18b20. I'd like to add another sensor to the same pin but not quite sure how to best do it. I didn't write this code myself. I'm using an NodeMCU devkit v0.9. The code below is just a section of the full code and there are separate scripts/tabs. Let me know if I should add anything else. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <Arduino.h> // not automatically included?
#include <OneWire.h> // for temp sensor
#include <Wire.h>    // I2C for ADC & RTC
#include <DHT.h>     // Humidity sensor    
#include "sens.h"

#define TEMP_PIN D2  // Where DS18B20 is connected
#define ADDR_LEN 8   // 1-Wire address length // NOT SURE WHAT THESE DO!!
#define DATA_LEN 9   // 1-Wire data length // NOT SURE WHAT THESE DO!!
#define HUMI_PIN D1  // Where the DHT11 is
#define RTC_ADDR 0x68  // Clock's I2C address
#define ADC_ADDR 0x48  // ADC's I2C address
#define SDA  D3    // I2C pins
#define SCL  D4

OneWire ow(TEMP_PIN); // Setup 1-Wire
byte addr[ADDR_LEN];  // To store 1-Wire address
byte data[DATA_LEN];  // To store 1-Wire data
DHT dht(HUMI_PIN, DHT11);  // Setup DHT

String leading0(const int c) {
  // Add a leading zero when stringifying a byte, used for the date
  return (c < 10) ? ("0" + String(c)) : String(c);
}

byte bin2bcd( const byte bin ) {
  // does as the name suggests, RTC uses BCD
  return (bin / 10 * 16) + (bin % 10);
}

byte bcd2bin( const byte bin ) {
  // does as the name suggests, RTC uses BCD
  return (bin / 16 * 10) + (bin % 16);
}

void senssetup() {
  // Setup sensors, called in setup()
  dht.begin();
  Wire.begin(SDA, SCL);
}

float gettemp() {
  int i = 0;
  ow.reset_search();
  do {} while (!ow.search(addr) && i++ < 0xff);
  // Search for 1-Wire devices
  if (i == 0x100) {
    if (debug) Serial.println("No devices found!");
    // Nothing connected
    return 0;
  }
  if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
    if (debug) Serial.println("CRC 1 failed!");
    // Checksum thing when getting device's address
    return -1;
  }
  if (addr[0] != 0x10 && addr[0] != 0x28) {
    if (debug) Serial.println("Not a DS18B20");
    // Wrong 1-Wire device
    return -2;
  }
  ow.reset();
  ow.select(addr);
  ow.write(0x44, 0);
  // HEX 44 tells it to convert temperature to readable binary
  delay(1000);
  // It takes ~750ms to convert data, 1s is used to be safe (1s is used in the default library too)
  if (!ow.reset()) {
    if (debug) Serial.println("Device not present");
    // Device has disconnected or broken during conversion?
    return -3;
  }
  ow.select(addr);
  ow.write(0xbe, 0);
  // Tells it we're reading
  for (i = 0; i < DATA_LEN; i++) {
    data[i] = ow.read(); // Read data
  }
  if (debug && OneWire::crc8(data, 8) != data[8])
    Serial.println( "CRC Check 2 failed" );
  // Checksum on data; this fails sometimes, I don't know why
  // temperature is always at the right value so ignore it
  int dat =  ((data[1] << 8) | data[0]);
  if (dat > 32767)
    dat -= 65536;
    // 16 bit data in 2's complement has a sign
    return dat / 16.0;
    // last 4 binary digits are fractional
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should split the search part from the getting temperature part.

NOTE: I'm not into NodeMCU, so you'll have to adapt it to that language before using it. I'd use C.

For instance, you can use a function to get all addresses of the temperature sensors and put them in an address array:

```
#define MAX_DEVICES 5
byte addresses[MAX_DEVICES][ADDR_LEN];
byte numOfAddresses;

void getAllAddresses()
{
    numOfAddresses = 0;
    ow.reset_search();
    byte address[ADDR_LEN];

    while (ow.search(address) && (numOfAddresses < MAX_DEVICES))
    {
        if ( OneWire::crc8( address, 7 ) != address[7] )
            continue; // CRC 1 failed

        if ( address[0] != 0x10 && address[0] != 0x28 )
            continue; // Not a DS18B20

        byte i;
        for (i = 0; i < ADDR_LEN; i++)
            addresses[numOfAddresses][i] = address[i];
        numOfAddresses++;
    }

    if (debug)
    {
        Serial.print("Found ");
        Serial.print(numOfAddresses);
        Serial.println(" temperature sensors");
    }
}
```

Then you can modify your function to get the temperature of the i-th sensor:

```
float gettemp(byte index)
{
    if (index >= numOfAddresses)
    {
        if (debug) Serial.println( "Index not valid" );
        return -200; // Don't use 0, -1, ..., since they are valid temperatures
    }

    ow.reset();
    ow.select(addresses[index]);
    ow.write(0x44, 0); // HEX 44 tells it to convert temperature to readable binary

    [...]
```

(just replace every call to `addr` with a call to `addresses[index]`.

In your code, then, instead of calling `gettemp` you will have to call `gettemp(0)` for the first sensor, `gettemp(1)` for the second and so on.

You will need to call `getAllAddresses` before the first call to gettemp, otherwise it will always return -200. You can call it at startup or every X seconds or at each measurement, that's completely up to you